# Datastore and task queue downtime correlation

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, task-queue, downtime

What correlation is there between datastore and task queue downtime?

(I'd like to use the task queue to defer some operations in the case of datastore downtime.)

Comment: Note: I could inspect the [system status](http://code.google.com/status/appengine/) data for this, but perhaps someone already knows the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Task Queue should be generally more durable than the datastore, as it's a simpler system, but there's no guarantee that they can't both experience a simultaneous outage.